# How do I use an embedded font when using ASPPdf?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, pdf-generation

I have a font in .otf format (I've converted it to .ttf too). My source for the PDF to be generated is `ImportFromUrl`. When I request this URL directly from a browser, the font works with the following CSS...

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: DINPro;
    src: url("http://myhost.com/css/fonts/DINPro.otf") format("opentype");
}

body{
    font-family: DINPro;
}
```

This has no effect on the generated PDF though. How can I use this font? I've tried converting the font to Cufon but the text was blurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code when creating the ASPPdf object...

```
Doc.Fonts.LoadFromFile Server.MapPath("/") & "\css\fonts\DINPro.ttf"
```

Epic... it works!

Comment: It ain't difficult just read the [documentation](http://www.asppdf.com/object_fonts.html#LoadFromFile), like I had to. The Persits documentation is always pretty good and easy to work with. If you want to manipulate the font properties don't forget to reference it back to an object i.e `Set font = doc.Fonts.LoadFromFile(Server.MapPath("/") & "\css\fonts\DINOro.ttf")`

Comment: Then you can access the [`Font` object properties](http://www.asppdf.com/object_font.html) useful for working out extents etc.

Comment: I couldn't see anything in the documentation about mixing ImportFromUrl, CSS and embedded fonts.

Comment: There's a great reference guide to [Font Management](http://www.asppdf.com/manual_06.html).